# Adicionar dados a um objeto/imagem no FabricJS

Tags: javascript, fabric.js

Preciso adicionar dados a um objeto no FabricJS e buscar eles novamente na hora de exportar o canvas.

Função que eu uso para adicionar um objeto:

```
function _addImageObject(imageURL) {
  fabric.util.loadImage(imageURL, function (imageLoaded) {

    var image = new fabric.Image(imageLoaded);

    image.set({
      borderColor: 'black',
      cornerColor: 'black',
      cornerStrokeColor: 'white',
      cornerSize: 11,
      transparentCorners: false,
    });

    canvas.add(image);
    canvas.centerObject(image);
    canvas.setActiveObject(image);
    canvas.renderAll();
  });
}
```

Função usada para buscar os objetos:

```
 function _canvasJSON() {
      try {
        let canvasCopy = _copyCanvas(canvas);

        let canvasJSON = {
          canvasImage: JSON.stringify(canvasCopy),
          svg: canvas.toSVG()
        };
        return canvasJSON;
      } catch (e) {
        canvas.renderAll();
      }
    }

function _copyCanvas() {
     let canvasString = JSON.stringify(canvas);
     return JSON.parse(canvasString);
}
```

Queria adicionar um objeto dentro dessa image, exemplo:

```
image.set('key', { values: 123});
```

E conseguir buscar ele no retorno do _canvasJSON();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para adicionar uma nova informação, é preciso criar um objeto, utilizar `obj.set()` e renderizar o canvas. Exemplo:

`var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
 obj.set('foo','bar');
 canvas.renderAll();`

Feito isso, a nova informação já estará dentro do seu objeto, porém ela ainda não está disponível no JSON.

Para isso, basta especificar no `JSON.stringify`.Exemplo:

`var json = JSON.stringify(canvas.toJSON(['foo']));`

Para buscar a informação inserida, basta busca-la dentro de um objeto. Exemplo:

 `var obj = canvas.getActiveObject();
 console.log(obj.foo);`